# UIScrollView doesn't stop at specific point it bounces back to top

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiscrollview

I'm very new to programming and objective C so you'll have to go easy on me. I'm sure some of the code in the app is probably unnecessary. I've searched google and StackOverflow for an answer but none of the solutions have worked for me, either because they're not the right solution or I just misunderstand the answers.
  i have  problem with my UIScrollView,  the  problem is that when i scroll down and since i let the UIScrollView go, it bounces back to the top and so i can't interact with the content I just scrolled to. my code is:

```
[self.scroller123 setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.scroller123 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1200)];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: add some more code ? it is difficult to give answer wrt above .

Comment: needs to set contentOffset when you scroll to specific point.

Comment: i m using only above code for scroller

Comment: if it automatically scroll bounces to back when you scroll then scrollView height size not higher than content size. So we must re increase the scrollView height of content size

Comment: can you plz tell me where is scrollviewsize ?? i m just to makesure

Comment: scrollView height size. if you set [scrollVIew setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1200)] then 1200 needs to be more when compare to content height

Comment: Further to what wesley is saying--your scroll view can be 320x480 and it's content size should be bigger than that, so 320x1200 could work. Also make sure self.scroller123 is connected and non-nil. (You can use `assert(self.scroller123 != nil)`)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `setContentSize` to scroll, that is for setting the size of scrollable content (so you usually do this only once)

Use `setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,Y_TO_SCROLL_TO);`

Comment: [self.scroller123 setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,1000)]; when i use this code my whole content will disappear from the screen .

Comment: Try a lower value then 1000, 1000 might be too much

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your scrollview's content size height as per your requirement. That's it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Set content size of Scroll view something like bellow ..

```
[self.scroller123 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scroller123.frame.size.width,__your_desired_height)];
```

and __your_desired_height should be equal to just the (height+origin of Y) of the last content inside your Scroll view .

Hope this will help you.